# Input text: how to force uppercase in the DOM?

Tags: html, dom, uppercase

I have this code to autocomplete text.

I know I can add style to the input to make it appear uppercase (style="text-transform:uppercase")

The problem with this: it won't change to uppercase below (DOM)

How to do this?

```js
var name1 = document.getElementById('name');

name1.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var result = document.querySelector('.X');
  result.innerHTML = this.value;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>What is your name? </label><input type="text" id="name" style="text-transform:uppercase" />

<p>Your name is: <span class="X"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has its own [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) method you can use:

```js
var name1 = document.getElementById('name');

name1.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var result = document.querySelector('.X');
  result.innerHTML = this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>What is your name? </label><input type="text" id="name" style="text-transform:uppercase" />

<p>Your name is: <span class="X"></span></p>
```

Or you could use the CSS text-transform you mentioned in your question and apply it to the span as well:

```js
var name1 = document.getElementById('name');

name1.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var result = document.querySelector('.X');
  result.innerHTML = this.value;
});
```

```css
span.X {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>What is your name? </label><input type="text" id="name" style="text-transform:uppercase" />

<p>Your name is: <span class="X"></span></p>
```